# How to show Context Menu in watchkit programmatically?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I want to show a context menu on tapping glance.
I am using a user activity method in InterfaceController (which handles tapping on Glance).

Is there any way to show a context menu programatically without “Force Touch”?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to show a context menu is with a Force Touch.

Separately, Glances are read-only, meaning that they do not support interaction. Tapping the Glance launches your WatchKit app, but that's all the interaction that's allowed. See the [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Mike for answer.